# Using for loop to check that the parameter in the function fulfils another parameter in the same function using for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

i have a problem with this question. Please help me

Implement a function called check_seating_arrangement(). This function takes in the
following 3 parameters:

- arrangement:
  It is the arrange of people in a counter clockwise manner from start to end of list

. For example, ['Alex', 'Gina', 'Timothy', 'Serena']
Note that the first person in the list and the last person in the list also sit next to each other.

- must_list:

A list of tuples, where each tuple has two strings representing the names of two people who
MUST sit next to each other. The list might be empty. You can assume that each name appearing here is a
name that has appeared in the list arrangement.

For my code i had,

```
def check_must(arrangement,must_list):
    for x in range (len(arrangement)):
        if x==0:
            if arrangement[x+1] not in must_list and arrangement[-1] not in must_list:
                return False
        
        elif arrangement[x]==arrangement[-1]:
            if arrangement[0] not in must_list and arrangement[x-1] not in must_list: 
                return False
        else:
            if arrangement[x+1] not in must_list and arrangement[x-1] not in must_list:
                return False
    
        
        
    return True
    
def check_seating_arrangement(arrangement, must_list):
    for i in range(len(must_list)):
        if arrangement in must_list[i]:
            check_must(arrangement,must_list[i])
        if check_must==True:
            return True
    return False
```

But i am consistently getting False as my answer when for this test case below, it should be True. Please help me fix my code. Thank you

you can use this for testing:

```
print (check_seating_arrangement(['Serena', 'Timothy', 'Lucy', 'Harry', 'Gina', 'Alex'], [('Serena', 'Alex'), ('Harry', 'Lucy')]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `must_list` is a set of tuples, but you constistently just check if one person is on that list of tuples. Which of course always is incorrect.

You need to loop not over the arrangement, but over the `must_list` and then check if each couple in that list are indeed sitting next to each other. Something like this:

```
def check(arrangement, must_list):
    for person_a, person_b in must_list:
        if abs(arrangement.index(person_a) - arrangement.index(person_b)) != 1:
            return False

    return True
```

Although that code doesn't see the first person in the list as sitting besides the last person, so you need to add a check for that. But that should get you forward.